# Python: Nested Inheritance, unable to add argument to a "grand-child" class

Tags: python, class, multiple-inheritance, super

I can't figure out why I can't add additional arguments to a "grandchild" class "Rival".  In order to be able to add an arg `group` to the grandchild class "Rival". I have to add the `group` argument to the child class "Bestie" from which "Rival" is inheriting from.  I don't even pass the additional class in the super.

See below the 2 codes.

- First one doesn't compile and shows group in rival as unresolved even if I declare it within the `super().__init__()` of Rival.
- Second works because I added `group` to both classes.

I just want to know why the first one works and the 2nd one doesn't. Trying to master classes in Python.

This code doesn't work.

```py
class Dog:
    breed: str
    strength: int = 0

    def __init__(self, breed, strength):
        """Constructor"""
        self.breed = breed
        self.strength = strength

    def hola(self):
        print(f"Hola {self.breed}")
        print(f"You this strong: {self.strength}")


class Bestie(Dog):

    def __init__(self, breed, strength, age, name):
        super().__init__(breed, strength)
        self.age = age
        self.name = name
        #self.group = group #omitting hear and in the argument breaks the code

    def friend_info(self):
        print(f"Hi {self.name}")
        print(f"you are {self.age} years old")
        print(f"you are {self.strength} on the strength scale and are a {self.breed}")


class Rival(Bestie):

    def __int__(self, breed, strength, age, name, group):
        super().__init__(breed, strength, age, name)
        self.group = group

    def rival_intro(self):
        print(f"I am {self.name}")
        print(f"I am {self.strength}, {self.age} y/o and am a {self.breed}")
        print(f"I am in {self.group}")


def main() -> None:
    """EntryPoint"""
    p = Bestie("Dane", 3, 12, "john", "group 1")
    p.hola()
    en = Rival("Dane", 3, 12, "john", "group 2")
    en.rival_intro()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# p: Dog = Dog("Chow", 5)
# print(p.breed)
```

Only able to work if I add the `group` arg to the Child class "Bestie" and the grandchild class "Rival"

Here is the code that compiles.

```py
class Dog:
    breed: str
    strength: int = 0

    def __init__(self, breed, strength):
        """Constructor"""
        self.breed = breed
        self.strength = strength

    def hola(self):
        print(f"Hola {self.breed}")
        print(f"You this strong: {self.strength}")


class Bestie(Dog):

    def __init__(self, breed, strength, age, name, group):
        super().__init__(breed, strength)
        self.age = age
        self.name = name
        self.group = group #omitting hear and in the argument breaks the code

    def friend_info(self):
        print(f"Hi {self.name}")
        print(f"you are {self.age} years old")
        print(f"you are {self.strength} on the strength scale and are a {self.breed}")


class Rival(Bestie):

    def __int__(self, breed, strength, age, name, group):
        super().__init__(breed, strength, age, name)
        self.group = group

    def rival_intro(self):
        print(f"I am {self.name}")
        print(f"I am {self.strength}, {self.age} y/o and am a {self.breed}")
        print(f"I am in {self.group}")


def main() -> None:
    """EntryPoint"""
    p = Bestie("Dane", 3, 12, "john", "group 1")
    p.hola()
    en = Rival("Dane", 3, 12, "john", "group 2")
    en.rival_intro()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# p: Dog = Dog("Chow", 5)
# print(p.breed)
```

Tried the 2 examples above and was expecting to add an argument on top of the inherited arguments, even if nested.

Comment: You are trying to create a `Bestie()` instance with a `group`. Why do expect that to work if that class doesn’t take a group?

Comment: I would have thought that the first snippet is what you actually want, except that you want to call `p = Bestie("Dane", 3, 12, "john")` without a `group`. The class `Bestie` neither needs nor uses a group.

Comment: Correct I just need group in Rival(), but it won't compile without it being in Bestie().  Comes as unresolved if omitted from Bestie().

Comment: Ok, I've actually tried your code. You need to make two changes to the first snippet: 1. `p = Bestie("Dane", 3, 12, "john")` (as I said above)  2. Change `__int__` to `__init__` in `class Rival`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Darn typo got me.